# How to show A is a subspace of B.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been having trouble trying to an assignment question on subspaces, is my understanding of them sound?

If A is a subspace of B, then A must firstly be a subset of B. That is to say, everything in A belongs in B. 
Next, We need to show that scalar multiplication and vector addition, by their definitions in B, are closed within A. So we show f(x1+x2)=f(x1)+f(x2). and kf(x1)=f(kx1)

Is my understanding accurate?

Comment: May I know, what is $f$?

Comment: oh yeah, i shouldn't have used that. But for the most part, the spaces we've been learning are function spaces. e.g f(z)=conjugate. But in this case, i meant f is the thing defining the space of B.

Comment: Nope. When you are investigating whether the subset is $B$ is closed under, say, addition, you are thinking about the addition of the original vector space $A$, that is the addition on functions themselves, not the addition of the variables.

Comment: you can easily check definsion  of vector space for $A$ or use Theorem: Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$, and let $W$ be a subset of $V$. Then $W$ is a subspace if and only if $W$ satisfies the following three conditions:

The zero vector, 0, is in W.
If $u$ and $v$ are elements of W, then the sum $u + v$ is an element of W;
If $u$ is an element of W and c is a scalar from K, then the product $cu$ is an element of $W$;

Comment: @SRX, f(x1+x2)=f(x1)+f(x2), doesn't that kind of show that the addition of variables is the same as the addition of functions?

Comment: @RaziehNoori, Doesn't the fact that the 0 vector is in A, follow from the fact that A is closed under scalar multiplication, so 0u=0? This would imply that the 0 vector is also a part of A.

Comment: @MrMachine If B is some space of functions, and A is a subset of B, showing A is closed under addition means that for all f1, f2 in A, (f1+f2) is in A. For example, if B is all functions from R to R, and A is all continuous functions, we know from first-year calculus that if f1 and f2 are continuous, f1+f2 is continuous. This shows that a is closed under addition. Make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense now. I've been getting subspace confused with showing a function is linear.

Answer (score 1):

Close, but not quite. Suppose $B$ is defined over a scalar field $S$.

To show $A$ is a subspace of $B$, you are right that you need to show 3 things: $A \subset B$, and $A$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

A being closed in these ways is slightly different than what you wrote.

A is closed under addition means $$\forall a,b\in A, (a + b)\in A.$$

A is closed under scalar mutliplication in $S$ means $$\forall a\in A, \forall s\in S, (sa) \in A.$$

Comment: Could you please explain how (f1+f2)(x) is different to f(x1+x2)? I don't even understand what (f1+f2)(x) would mean. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @MrMachine (f1+f2)(x) = f1(x) + f2(x). It's just notation. For example, if f1(x) = 3x and f2(x) = x^2, then (f1+f2)(x) = f1(x) + f2(x) = 3x + x^2

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of a subspace for this purpose is sometimes inconvenient. But, fortunately, there is a theorem simplifying this job: Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field; let $V$ be a vector space; and let $W \subset V$. Then $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if (i) $0_{V} \in W$, (ii) $x+y \in W$ for all $x,y \in W$, and (iii) $cx \in W$ for all $c \in \mathbb{F}$ and all $x \in W$.
(You may try to prove this theorem, which is not difficult.)

I hope the above helps.